# STS unable to find certification

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I have downloaded the latest version of spring tool suite (STS 3.6.2), when I tried to import spring getting started content, it return as below error:

Get started Guide
SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have setup the proxy to visit internet, but I don't know how to import certifications in STS.
Please help.
Thanks.

James

Comment: I am not certain of this, but this is probably something you will have to ask help from your local system administrator. My guess is you are in a corporate network environment and they are doing something to the way your computer validates security certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the file named “openssl.cnf”. Just delete it or rename it.

Comment: Why should we delete that file? What problem does that  solve? Do you have more information?

Comment: This can solve the problem. I fixed it by this way. I think the default config of openssl lib conflicting with STS. @EmilVikström

Comment: is it in the STS folder? because I have one in Git folder, but i guess that's an important one!

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem and tried this:
Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections Change mode to Manual

It works fine now.

Comment: On the Network Connections change the value of Active Provider dropdown to Manual.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the *Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection*

select the Active Provider option: **Manual**

then Click on Apply Button

*It will be work*

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu you can run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

Source: [Ubuntu Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

If still not getting. Then remove s from https://start.spring.io. It should look like [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDc2o.png)

The above image is referred from spring tool suite official website. When you install a new sts it automatically adds secure connection. Hence we can access to that website currently with out secure only.

Answer (score 0):

The default url i had was: https://start.spring.io
When i removed the 's' --> http://start.spring.io
Then it worked.
I guess it is to do with my network settings

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, so created project from spring initializer https://start.spring.io/ and imported to STS and it loaded all the required .m2 files able to run the application